# Problem with short-code with two value from the attributes array

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I have a problem with my shortcode that I created to run in a wordpress environment.

I'm not an expert with shortcode, that's the deal:

```
add_shortcode('key_value' , 'key_value' );
function key_value( $atts, $content = null ) {
  $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
     'title' => '',
     'url'   => '',
  ), $atts );
  if ($atts['title']) {    
    $html = '<li><strong>'.$atts['title'].': </strong>'.$content.'</li>';
  } elseif ($atts['url'] && $atts['title']) {
    $html = '<li><a href="'.$atts['url'].'" target="_blank">'.$atts['title'].'</a></li>';
  }

  return $html;
}
```

I want to return the second if statement because I've got a bunch of shortcode like that:

```
[key_value title="Delivery"]Fast[/key_value]
[key_value title="Duration"]2 weeks[/key_value]
```

And they work fine but the last one:

```
[key_value title="Info Session" url="/info/"][/key_value]
```

doesn't work and I don't understand why because, if I var_dump my array $atts, I'm able to see both value.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is getting into the first condition. Change the logic to execute first the `else` condition, or in other words, if have both attributes use it, else check only for title:

```
if ($atts['url'] && $atts['title']) {
    $html = '<li><a href="'.$atts['url'].'" target="_blank">'.$atts['title'].'</a></li>';
} elseif ($atts['title']) {    
    $html = '<li><strong>'.$atts['title'].': </strong>'.$content.'</li>';
}
```